# Using LEFT( ), RIGHT( ) and LEN( ) functions with custom formatted cells in excel

Tags: excel, analytics, data-analysis, spreadsheet

I am trying te get the first 10 charachters  of custom formatted time and date cell using the LEFT( ) FUNCTION but it retruns a floating number and I don't understand why is that happening. and the same thing happens if i use RIGHT( ) or LEN( )

[image: [this what i am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJyiH.png)]

Comment: Date/times are formatted numbers.

Comment: What you see in the cell and what the cell actually contains can be two very different things.  Yours is a date, so is a serial number starting at 1 on 1st Jan 1900 going up to 45369 today (18th March 2024).  If you just want the date (the first 10 characters in your formatted cell) try using `=INT(C2)` for the date, or as @MayukhBhattacharya said - `MOD(C2,1)` for the time and then format the cell as either `yyyy-mm-dd` or `hh:mm:ss`.